# How can I fill in some properties of a Partial and let the type system know about it?

Tags: typescript

I have a `Partial<T>`, and over the course of a routine, parts of it get filled in. I would like the type to evolve as the routine progresses to understand that some properties are no longer undefined. Example:

```
type PartialUserInfo = {
  name?: string;
  age?: number;
  shoeBrand?: string;
}


function doSomeUserStuff(userId: string, info: PartialUserInfo) {

  // info.name's type is `undefined | string`
  console.log(info.name.length); // error, possibly undefined!

  info = fillInUserName(userId, info);
  
  // now info.name's type is just `string`
  console.log(info.name.length) // ok!

  info = fillInShoeBrand(userId, info);

  console.log(info.name.length, info.shoeBrand.length); // both fields are now known to be defined
}
```

So I'm looking for an implementation of `fillInUserName` that returns a stronger info than it was passed. Here I've manually **specified the return type to illustrate**, but this doesn't work (and would be awkward even if it did).

```
function fillInUserName(id: string, info: PartialUserInfo): {
    name: string;
    age?: number;
    shoeSize?: number
} {
  if (info.name == undefined) {
    info.name = lookUpUserName(id);
  }
  return info;
}
```

I'd also hope that it takes the current optionality of the properties it didn't affect, so that e.g. it would return `age?: number` or `age: number` depending on what was passed in.

I considered trying to make this work with the `asserts x is Y` return type, but wanted some advice first.

---

For context, I have a bunch of utility methods that need to operate on bits of user context. Looking up that context is expensive, so I'd like to pass around this little cache. I'd like the type system to warn me if I haven't guaranteed if a value I'm using has been defined yet.

Comment: TypeScript only does [assignment narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#assignments) if the variable being assigned has a union type.  Since `PartialUserInfo` is not a union, then `info = fillInUserName(userId, info)` will never work.  You could write assertion functions to do this, but they have weird caveats and restrictions.  See [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NdO0kw) for one possibility.  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz yeah, assertions feel "weird" but it does seem to do what I asked so, yes, I think you should write it up. The use of the `&` in the assertion is new to me too, looks interesting!

Comment: That `&` seems to be a typo  and was ignored.  So, uh, forget that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript only performs [assignment narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#assignments) if the variable to which you're assigning is of a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types).  Since `user` is of type `PartialUserInfo`, and `PartialUserInfo` is a single object type and not a union (the *properties* might be unions that include `undefined`, but the object type itself is not a union), then any code of the form `info = ⋯;` will not narrow the apparent type of `info`, no matter what `⋯` is.

TypeScript doesn't really model arbitrary narrowings.  As you alluded to, you can use [assertion functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) to customize narrowing the apparent types of one of the function's arguments, but this requires some refactoring.  And assertion functions have some weird caveats: the big one is that the assertion function must have a *static type annotation*.  A `function` declaration is fine, but a factory that returns assertion functions is hard to use.  So while I'd like to write something that *generates* your `fillInXXX()` functions for you, I'll have to make do with a single `fillIn` function that takes more arguments.

That refactoring might look like:

```
function fillInProp<
    K extends PropertyKey, V,
    T extends Partial<Record<K, V>>
>(
    k: K,
    lookup: (id: string) => V,
    id: string,
    t: T
): asserts t is T & { [P in K]: V } {
    if (t[k] === undefined) {
        (t as Record<K, V>)[k] = lookup(id);
    }
}
```

So if you call `fillInProp(k, lookup, id, t)`, then the type of `t` will be narrowed so that it is known to have a defined property at the `k` key.  Let's try it:

```
function doSomeUserStuff(userId: string, info: PartialUserInfo) {
    fillInProp("name", lookUpUserName, userId, info);
    info // PartialUserInfo & {name: string}
    console.log(info.name.length) // ok!

    fillInProp("shoeBrand", lookUpShoeBrand, userId, info);
    info // PartialUserInfo & {name: string} & {shoeBrand: string};
    console.log(info.name.length, info.shoeBrand.length); // ok!
}
```

Looks good.  After you call `fillInProp("name", lookupUserName, userId, info)`, the compiler knows that `info` has a `string`-valued `name` property.  And likewise after the call to `fillInProp("shoeBrand", lookUpShoeBrand, userId, info)`, the `shoeBrand` property has been narrowed to `string`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMGAbVBJMAFATnABwB4BYAKEUsQGlEBTADyjrABMBnRPQu3KAT2p1+AGkQA1EeSqIAKvSYsOXAIZ8YK1EQBKdCHFysi1MeIB8Z8mYAU0qgGsAXDSkUqqOHHsgCz6zFZndihcGDAAcwBKRABeMwlXGQCgkLDwxKooZ1lySOcVdnZeKE4oRBhOeQAyRABvRABtbHKkagBdZ3FEAF86u0oYYERrKAb7NtiYmMRwVjoUMDpWaNr+mWGygsRdfUNjUzNIsYnpjy8ff2WAbjXu8juycjmIVDU6ZHBoeCQz+wBVAh-Iq4AByKgAtnRLilQhE8ohgrDwjcyM9Xrh3qBILAEIhfgCAMoACzgdAAQrgVGxoQjUnCYWkUeRyAICO9sGpYJogbwsMA4LE+m5KGAIXQAPwMiIomQqcIS5xgEDggBGvBlVHYJPJlLYktpSJRD2ZjzIWK+uNYcAJcEhPNwBKgIGAwGsIGBGECBrSYjC-OcHPU3I9YH5KzWKHQWG4BGsACJRZC42J8YDgWDIWJ3bzWL7Q3BIhqBvnEAB6UuqIOoe18gU1WqJuhS8IPGT6MDsOCoOgAOg84X8+Z7jb7LHCUCJ0XLiC8AEITTJI5gcPhY3GtaSKVTWMm8Z5-gRiZvdbmZh7T36C0WWvyyxXA1zqyHb-XG83evWNzrt+-r+3O92fZwAOl7DmKo4RBOeb8j2X5bmwEHjpOVx3jO9jzmQ3RAA)

Comment: I greatly appreciate the genericness of your answer! Just for curiosity's sake though, in a world where "fillInXXX" each actually have different logic and I'm hand-writing them all anyways, it seems I can write the return types thus: `function fillInName(i: PartialUserInfo): asserts i is PartialUserInfo & { name: string }`

Comment: Yes, you can. .